# Sampling points in a vector

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry, mesh, sampling

I have a vector **_pts** that contains values for (x,y,z), i.e. a point in 3D. Starting with _pts[0], I want to select those points whose distance between previously selected points is bigger than **sampleRadius**.

Here is my code but apparently something's wrong because is selecting a lot of points instead of just selecting a few.
Can anyone see what am I doing wrong? Probably you would need more code to see what can be missed, but I would also appreciate any idea on how can I implement this.

```
float distance;
bool distanceIsOk;

//PICK A POINT IN VECTOR _pts
for (int cPIdx = 0; cPIdx < _pts.size(); cPIdx++) {
    distanceIsOk = true;
    //CHECK DISTANCE AGAINST PREVIOUSLY PICKED POINTS
    for (int dPIdx = 0; dPIdx < indeces.size(); dPIdx++) {
        distance = sqrt(
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[0] - _pts[dPIdx].v[0])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[0] - _pts[dPIdx].v[0]) +
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[1] - _pts[dPIdx].v[1])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[1] - _pts[dPIdx].v[1]) +
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[2] - _pts[dPIdx].v[2])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[2] - _pts[dPIdx].v[2])
                        );
        //IF DISTANCE IS <= SUBSAMPLERADIUS FOR AT LEAST ONE PREVIOUSLY SELECTED POINT
        if (distance <= subsampleRadius) {
            //DISCARD THE POINT
            distanceIsOk = false;
            dPIdx += indeces.size();
        }
    }
    //OTHERWISE INCLUDE THAT POINT
    if (distanceIsOk == true) {
        indeces.push_back(cPIdx);
    }
}
```

Comment: A workable code... you mean to post the whole code? If so, I cannot is a big code. I think the idea is clearly expressed though.

Comment: I think the problem is not precisely defined. If I imagine three points: A, B, and C with A and B being closer to each other than your sampleRadius and C being farther from A and B with the distance greater than sampleRadius, what should the algorithm return, {A, C} or {B, C} ?

Comment: @Archie You save A. Then you check B agains the previously saved points. In this case you compare distance between A and B. Is distance <= SampleRadius? yes: discard B, no: save B. Then check C against the previously saved points, i.e. just A (B was discarded) is distance <= SampleRadius? yes: discard C, no: save C.

Comment: So you have to rephrase your problem: find just one (any) of possible sets of points that satisfies the criteria. Because as you explain, the result of your algorithm will depend on order of points in the input list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Instead of

```
        distance = sqrt(
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[0] - _pts[dPIdx].v[0])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[0] - _pts[dPIdx].v[0]) +
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[1] - _pts[dPIdx].v[1])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[1] - _pts[dPIdx].v[1]) +
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[2] - _pts[dPIdx].v[2])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[2] - _pts[dPIdx].v[2])
```

it should be

```
        distance = sqrt(
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[0] - _pts[indeces[dPIdx]].v[0])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[0] - _pts[indeces[dPIdx]].v[0]) +
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[1] - _pts[indeces[dPIdx]].v[1])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[1] - _pts[indeces[dPIdx]].v[1]) +
                        (_pts[cPIdx].v[2] - _pts[indeces[dPIdx]].v[2])*(_pts[cPIdx].v[2] - _pts[indeces[dPIdx]].v[2])
```